# Limiting embedded document size

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

I have `user` schema for `MongooseJS` with embedded document `photos` by `PhotoSchema`:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    email    : { type : String, index : 'unique', set: toLower }
  , login    : { type : String, index : 'unique' }
  , password : { type : String } 
  , salt     : { type : String }
  , photos   : [ PhotoSchema ]
  , name     : { type : String }
});
```

When I retreive one `user`, how can I limit quantity of `photos` in result set?

Or should I retrive all photos that user have (even if there is a million)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't retreive users with limited quantity of photos, but you can:

1.Load user(s) without photos first:

```
db.users.find( { _id: 1 }, { photos : 0 } );
```

2.Load just user photos thats you need:

```
db.users.find({}, {photos:{$slice: [20, 10]}}) // skip 20, limit 10
```

[Documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields)